# Gitlab issue close automatically

Tags: gitlab

I wonder if there is a way to close a issue automatically at a certain time like every Friday at 18:00 if that issue has a label or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab did not include such a feature.
They use their own [bot](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-triage) to triage issues and merge requests.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a feature of GitLab itself. However, you could run a [scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) that uses the [issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) to do this.

To make sure the scheduled pipeline has the properly scoped API access, you can generate a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) and place it in the CI/CD variables.

The scheduled pipeline does not even necessarily have to be configured in the same project in which you want issues to be expired, if you're concerned about it triggering existing pipeline jobs. For example, you can create a new project called "issue cleanup" and setup the pipeline there to cleanup issues of one or more other projects on the schedule